# last comment gets saved twice on my file and therefore gets printed on the webpage twice

Tags: php, html

i am writing a comment block in my website. i save the comment in a file and print the contents on

the webpage. but the problem is when i refresh the webpage the last

comment gets displayed twice.

so i have used a logic, that is i search the last comment in my comment database file and if it finds it does not write on the file.

Here's my code

```
<html>


<body>

<form   method="GET">

<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="comments" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" >

</form>

</body>

</html>




<?php
$refresh = 0;

$comments = file_get_contents("comments.txt");
$file_comments_len = strlen($comments);

$current_comments = $_GET["comments"];
$current_comments_len = strlen($current_comments);


for($i = 0; $i<= $file_comments_len; $i++){

    $sub = substr($comments, $i, (($i+$current_comments_len-1 )) ); 
    echo $sub."<br>";
    echo $i;
    if( $sub == $comments){
        $refresh = 100;
        break;
    }

}

if( ($_GET["comments"]!=null) && ($refresh==0) ){
    $comments = /*"Anonymous said:<br>".*/$_GET["comments"]."<br><br>";
    //$file_comments = fopen("comments.txt","a");
    //fwrite($file_comments,$comments);
    //fclose($file_comments);
    file_put_contents( "comments.txt", $comments, FILE_APPEND );

    $_GET["comments"] = null;
    $comments = null;

}

//$file_comments2 = fopen("comments.txt", "r");
$comments = file_get_contents("comments.txt");
echo $comments;
//fclose($file_comments2);

$_GET["comments"] = null;
$comments = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just try with change the variable name like $comments is used more thane twice.

```
if( ($_GET["comments"]!=null) && ($refresh==0) ){
$comments_new = /*"Anonymous said:<br>".*/$_GET["comments"]."<br><br>";
//$file_comments = fopen("comments.txt","a");
//fwrite($file_comments,$comments);
//fclose($file_comments);
file_put_contents( "comments.txt", $comments_new, FILE_APPEND );
$_GET["comments"] = null;
$comments_new = null;
}
```

This may helpful!!

Comment: i have got rid of my problem. there must have been some issue in the software to run .php files on my computer. when i uploaded the file it worked perfectly.